# I can't use Intel GVT-g on KVM on my guest operating system Windows 10

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I can't use Intel GVT-g on KVM on my guest operating system Windows 10

Hardware: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700 CPU @ 3.40GHz (Skylake 6th-generation Core)

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Part of `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_iommu=on modprobe.blacklist=radeon i915.enable_gvt=1"
```

```
$ ls /sys/bus/pci/devices

0000:00:00.0  0000:00:02.0  0000:00:16.0  0000:00:1c.0  0000:00:1f.0  0000:00:1f.3  0000:00:1f.6  0000:01:00.1
0000:00:01.0  0000:00:14.0  0000:00:17.0  0000:00:1d.0  0000:00:1f.2  0000:00:1f.4  0000:01:00.0  0000:01:00.2
```

```
$ lspci

･･･
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
･･･
```

```
$ cat /etc/modules
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.
```

```
$ dmesg | grep i915
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-37-generic root=UUID=238b3cf4-75da-41b4-908e-72ae024c975c ro quiet splash intel_iommu=on modprobe.blacklist=radeon i915.enable_gvt=1 vt.handoff=7
[    0.053940] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-37-generic root=UUID=238b3cf4-75da-41b4-908e-72ae024c975c ro quiet splash intel_iommu=on modprobe.blacklist=radeon i915.enable_gvt=1 vt.handoff=7
[    6.218550] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] VT-d active for gfx access
[    6.218674] i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
[    6.243296] i915 0000:00:02.0: Direct firmware load for i915/gvt/vid_0x8086_did_0x1912_rid_0x06.golden_hw_state failed with error -2
[    6.258513] i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=io+mem
[    6.258551] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Disabling framebuffer compression (FBC) to prevent screen flicker with VT-d enabled
[    6.260816] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/skl_dmc_ver1_27.bin (v1.27)
[    6.303105] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20201103 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[    6.327065] fbcon: i915drmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    6.327220] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] fb0: i915drmfb frame buffer device
[    6.421796] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
```

```
$ lsmod | grep i915
i915                 2297856  64
drm_kms_helper        237568  2 amdgpu,i915
cec                    53248  2 drm_kms_helper,i915
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 amdgpu,i915
drm                   548864  12 gpu_sched,drm_kms_helper,amdgpu,drm_ttm_helper,i915,ttm
video                  53248  2 asus_wmi,i915
```

```
$ ls /sys/class/drm/
card0  card0-DP-1  card0-HDMI-A-1  card0-HDMI-A-2  renderD128  ttm  version
```

```
$ ls /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:00\:02.0/mdev_supported_types/
ls: '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:02.0/mdev_supported_types/' にアクセスできません: そのようなファイルやディレクトリはありません

'/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:02.0/mdev_supported_types/'

The directory does not exist.
```

How can I use Intel GVT-g on KVM on my guest operating system Windows 10 with my system?

Comment: This can be a pretty complicated process. I would suggest [going through this guide](https://mathiashueber.com/pci-passthrough-ubuntu-2004-virtual-machine/) first, then asking *specific* questions on here if elements of the setup fail.

Comment: The link by @matigo is great for GPU passthrough, but GVT-g that is asked for is actually about splitting your GPU into multiple mediated devices and passing them individually. I've written about it [here](https://cpaelzer.github.io/blogs/006-mediated-device-to-pass-parts-of-your-gpu-to-a-guest/) which might help you to get started.

Comment: @Christian Ehrhardt
Thank you for your valuable article.
However, the method in this article did not work with Intel GVT-g on KVM on my guest operating system Windows 10.

Comment: I only used the same technology with Nvidia vGPUs for Windows guests so far, are these any errors in particular that looks like a bug to be fixed or just issues to set it up right?

Comment: This Question isn't about GPU passthrough.

GVT-g tecnology is had by Intel's GPU only.

Nvidia's GPU don't have GVT-g tecnology.

GVT-g that is asked for is actually about splitting my GPU into multiple mediated devices and passing them individually.